# Asymptotic properties of the cumulative normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Given a standard normal distribution $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Denote

$$g(x)= 1-\int_{-\infty}^{x} p(z) dz$$

In fact, when $x \to +\infty$ then $g(x) \to 0$. I want to find a function, e.g $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} =const$

Any suggestion for as simple as $f(x)$ can be?

Comment: Is the constant allowed to be 0? If so, simply letting $f(x)$ be a non-zero constant would work.

Comment: No, the constant is not a zero number.